# mongodb: Zulu dates

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Question is straightforward.

It's not clear to me if mongodb is ALWAYS storing dates in UTC, so in `zulu(Z)` zone, regardless if date string contains a zone?

I've tested with:

```
> db.products.updateOne( { _id: 1 }, { $set: { item: "apple" }, $setOnInsert: { dateAdded: new Date() } }, { upsert: true });
> db.products.updateOne( { _id: 2 }, { $set: { item: "jordi" }, $setOnInsert: { dateAdded: new Date("1982-05-19T14:00:00.000+05:00") } }, { upsert: true });
```

I detected that second date is stored a `Zulu(Z)`:

```
db.products.find();
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    dateAdded: ISODate("2022-02-02T15:40:02.457Z"),
    item: 'apple'
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    dateAdded: ISODate("1982-05-19T09:00:00.000Z"),
    item: 'jordi'
  }
]
```

Related question is, how do I need to make date range queries?

I mean, ranged dates queries have to have dates using `Zulu` zone?

I've tested a bit. It seems I'm able to set range queries using whichever timezone and they are transalted to `Zulu`:

```
db.products.find({ dateAdded: { $gt: ISODate("1982-05-19T13:00:00.000+05:00"), $lt: ISODate("1982-05-20T00:00:00.000Z") } });
[
  {
    _id: 2,
    dateAdded: ISODate("1982-05-19T09:00:00.000Z"),
    item: 'jordi'
  }
]
```

Comment: Yes, all times are stored as UTC time - always and only. If your pass `ISODate("1982-05-19T13:00:00.000+05:00")` then time is converted to UTC. `ISODate()` is just an alias for `new Date()`. If you like to preserve the input time zone, then you must store it in a separate field.

Answer (score 0):

The internal representation of a date doesn't refer to UTC or any other time zone, but represents a specific instant in the history of the world. Specifically, [the MongoDB manual says](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#std-label-document-bson-type-date):

> BSON Date is a 64-bit integer that represents the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970). This results in a representable date range of about 290 million years into the past and future.

So, a date and time of "1969-12-31T16:00:00 America/Los_Angeles" or 1970-01-01T03:00:00 Africa/Nairobi" would both be stored as the number zero, because they correspond to the arbitrary "epoch", chosen to fall at "1970-01-01T00:00 UTC".

For *input*, dates constructed from any of those date strings would result in the same internal value, so compare as equal.

For *output*, you can choose the timezone to display (e.g. which of the three strings above you want to show for an internal value of zero) by using [the timezone argument to $dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/). If you don't specify it, UTC will be used as a default, but that doesn't reflect the internal storage, just an arbitrary default for that parameter.